# laravel 5 only root route works

Tags: php, controller, routes, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I am using Ubuntu 15.04. I installed Laravel Framework version 5.1.7 (LTS) using composer and a lamp server using `$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` command (I didn't install Homestead). I am using `PhpStorm 8.0.3` as IDE.

I created three routes and a controller. The `PagesController.php` file looks like this:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return 'Welcome to my homepage!';
    }

    public function about()
    {
        return 'Learn a little about me.';
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

and the `routes.php` looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');

Route::get('hello', 'PagesController@hello');
```

Whenever I go to `http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/` (or `http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/index.php`) it works fine and shows me the `Welcome to my homepage!` message. But whenever I go to `http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/hello` or `http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/about`, what I get is `404 Not Found` message.

Also, the `.htaccess` file which is located at `my-first-app/public` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I have tried:

- I tried `http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/index.php/hello` or  `http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/index.php/about` but it doesn't work either.
- I entered command `sudo a2enmod rewrite` followed by `sudo service apache2 restart` but it doesn't work either.
- I tried `composer dump-autoload` but it doesn't work either.
- I changed `AllowOverride` from `None` to `All` in `apache2.conf`. Now part of it looks like this:

  ```
  <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all denied
  </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share>
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /srv/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ```

  but it doesn't solve the problem either.

**Update (7/15/2015):**

The result of running `php artisan route:list` looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI   | Name | Action                                     | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /     |      | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@index |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | about |      | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@about |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | hello |      | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@hello |            |
+--------+----------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Run "php artisan route:list" and paste the output. You should see all defined routes there.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Thanks for your reply. I added the result at the end of my question.

Comment: Could you add dd('test'); at the top of your index file, go to "http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/index.php/about" and see if test will be output? this way we'd know if it's something with rewrites or with Laravel code

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I added `dd('test');` at the top of `index.php` file. Now, when I go to  `http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/index.php` it shows me a blank page and when I go to `http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/index.php/about` it gives me the same `404 Not Found
` message.

Comment: I meant die,not dd :) Anyway, now we know it's something wrong with the rewrites. I'll try to find the reason later, you can search yourself for some issues with the rewrites as it's for sure not Laravel routing.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Thank you for your help. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Hey, let's change the RewriteEngine to "off" in the .htaccess for a moment. Does it work then?

Comment: @hogan I changed `RewriteEngine` to `Off`. The situation is same as before.

Comment: @today: Then it seems like it's not mod_rewrite. To make sure, restart Apache. In your routes, add this for another test and open the page: `Route::get('test', function(){ echo 'test works';});`

Comment: @hogan Unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Comment: $today: Does this work? `http://localhost:63342/my-first-app/public/test` If not, what do you see? And what do the Apache logs say?

Comment: Would you please run `php artisan serve --port 8000 --host 127.0.0.1` in your consol (maybe terminal since you are in Linux) and then navigate to `http://localhost:8000/about` and tell us what happens? Also, remember you may have to start your apache server on your lampp.

Comment: @hogan No, it doesn't work. It shows the `404 not found` message. @CrackingTheCode I did what you said and went to `http://localhost:8000/about` It shows the correct `Learn a little about me! `message. So what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @today: So it has something todo with your environment and not laravel. What do the Apache logs say?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 13):

Enable apache2 rewrite module:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart the apache2 server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And make sure that `AllowOverride All` to your apache2 config file.

Comment: This is the simplest way for linux. It works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I have been having this annoying problem for a long time. Open `.htaccess` file in public folder and replace the following code, make a backup of your original code just in case.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this solution.. it works for me.

Answer (score 9):

Step 1: Enable mod_rewrite

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

Step 2: To activate these changes restart Apache2

> sudo service apache2 restart

Now check your web page is it working or not.
If not follow Step 3.

Step 3: Edit Apache Configuration file

To Edit run below command:

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Then add following block of code below `<VirtualHost *:80>`

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Save the file and exit.

Restart apache2:

> sudo service apache2 restart

It should be working fine now.

Comment: I updated your answer to include `ReWriteEngine On` just for good measure

Answer (score 2):

Altering .htaccess file would work in this scenario per laravel 5 official document as below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times Beginners do not create `.htaccess` file in their project please make sure to copy `.htaccess` file from public folder and paste it on your project's root directory...

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 11, Laravel Version:8.83.10

I had similar problem.

```
pico /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

followed by changing following block solved problem

```
<Directory /usr/share>  
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

putting /  at start, end of route is not important