# File Not Found in Laravel project but route is set

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am trying to get to a page I added to my route but it says "File Not Found".

I have set up a route to the WebsiteController but that didn't work. The index route '/' is working as expected. I tried manually creating the controller and using php artisan to see if there was a difference but it's the same. I also tried change the "post" to a "get", "any", etc.

Routes

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/website/{url}', 'WebsiteController@index');
```

WebsiteController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WebsiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index($url) {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

I expected to see what I have put in the URL after 'website/', it simply says "File not found".

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the route to expect a parameter:

```
Route::post('/website/{url}', 'WebsiteController@index');
```

Because you wrote `website/` as the address, you did not provide the parameter that the route was expecting (`url` in this case).  If your route was:

```
Route::post('/website', 'WebsiteController@index');
```

This would have worked, but failed when it got to the controller because the `index` method was expecting a parameter.

Simple fix: change the route as above, or add the parameter at the end of the url:  `website/someUrl`.  Also make sure you are using the right method (`post` vs `get`) - if typing in the address bar, remember to use `get` in your `Route` method.

Comment: Sorry, I said "I expected to see what I have put in the URL after 'website/'" meaning I had put something after website/. Which I have put website/sdf

Comment: Ah - I see.  Are you typing this into your web browser?

Comment: Try get instead of post and dump it in your index method dd($url); then you should see what you entered

Comment: Excellent - please see the last bit of my answer - change route from POST to GET and I think yer all set :)  IE    `Route::get(...)`

Comment: @Watercayman I have also done that haha. Sorry, I think it's just being difficult with me

Comment: Did you set up your nginx server manually? what operating system and web server you're using?

Comment: @latr.88 I set it all up using Homestead and vagrant

Comment: lol.  well shoot.  If the `/` is working, then this should work:  `Route::get('website/{url}', 'WebsiteController@index');`  Note I removed the `/` from the beginning.  Strange

Comment: @latr.88 I'm not sure if it'll make any difference but the way I've set it up is I'm treating it as a projects folder under domain of projects.test where this particular project is called seo-laravel so when I'm using the route '/' the url is [link](http://projects.test/seo-laravel/) . Is it possible that I'm causing confusion in my code?

Comment: It seems like a vagrant, web server error to me, not laravel's. Try searching for vagrant file not found and see some solutions

Comment: As long as you have the right directory in your vagrant config file it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @latr.88 I've found it's a common issue on several websites [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/500-error-when-trying-to-load-any-view-besides-the-homeindex-view) [link](https://laravel.io/forum/09-15-2015-removing-indexphp-from-url-laravel-5116) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435283/laravel-5-only-root-route-works) still can't get it to work and for the .conf file solution recommended I don't even have the file haha hopefully this comment will help others while I can't help myself

Comment: I had it my self sometime go, but it was because I set up my nginx server manually and missed the right entry.